# How to overwrite template.php file

Tags: functions, child-theme

I'm using a child theme for my website. I tried to enqueue `template.php` file wich exists in `includes` folder but making any change in the template.php file of the child folder didn't affect pages. Enqueuing other files works perfect. Here is the code of my `function.php` in the childe theme folder

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:


if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css' );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' );

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_child_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_child_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_child', get_stylesheet_uri() ); 
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_child_css', 999 );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your folder structure of your parent and child theme structure? Just related to template.php

Comment: template.php files have similar structure in both parent and child theme:
`themename/includes/template.php` 
and 
`themename-child/includes/template.php`

Comment: How about the code that include the `template.php` file. Is that a page template or something else. If template.php is a page template, it should work.

Comment: No it contains a set of functions

Comment: can you send me the parent `template.php` via pastebin or something. I need to know what the file has, because if it's the set of functions, you won't override it by doing like that

Comment: Here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/8HKPeNuf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

In your parent `template.php`. Some function were not wrapped in:

```
if( !function_exists('function_name') ) {
   // function content
}
```

So you won't able to override that function. Make sure to wrap parent function that tend to be override in child by above code.

FYI, for function, you don't need to create a file with same structure in parent. Actually, it has no effect :). Just place it in functions.php or another file that **IS INCLUDED** by functions.php

For example, to override function named `function_name` in your child theme `functions.php`:

```
function function_name() {}
```

What you did is overriding page template file.